# Debugging Code that uses predict() in R

Tags: r, debugging, random-forest, predict

When running this code:

```
predict(rfm, x[split.idx[[i]], sig_otu], type="prob")
```

I get this error message:

```
Error in x[, vname, drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds
```

Does this error message arise from incorrect bracketing? I've tried re-arranging brackets, adding parentheses, etc. However, I will still get this error message.

split.idx is a list of 8
    str(split.idx)

```
List of 8

 $ 1: Named int [1:10] 2 3 13 17 34 40 72 70 30 27
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "01" "09" "017" "025" ...
 $ 2: Named int [1:10] 21 32 67 52 12 55 36 37 24 31
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "02" "010" "018" "026" ...
 $ 3: Named int [1:10] 49 58 64 8 54 62 1 41 39 35
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "03" "011" "019" "027" ...
 $ 4: Named int [1:10] 46 59 20 43 47 4 57 76 33 29
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "04" "012" "020" "028" ...
 $ 5: Named int [1:10] 42 45 69 71 44 38 7 10 9 78
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "05" "013" "021" "029" ...
 $ 6: Named int [1:10] 15 5 73 61 63 25 28 48 53 14
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "06" "014" "022" "030" ...
 $ 7: Named int [1:10] 68 6 23 11 65 16 66 26 22 56
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:10] "07" "015" "023" "031" ...
 $ 8: Named int [1:9] 51 60 74 75 50 19 77 18 79
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:9] "08" "016" "024" "032" ...
```

This is the type of variable sig_otu is:

```
str(sig_otu)
Named int [1:56] 12 26 44 50 79 131 144 178 240 253 ...
   - attr(*, "names")= chr [1:56] "" "" "" "" ...
```

This is the value assigned to rfm:

```
rfm <- randomForest(x[-split.idx[[i]]], sig_otu], y[-split.idx[[i]]])
```

X is a large matrix with dim [1] 79, 1924.

Y is discrete factor with length 79 and 2 levels.

I hope that my question is clear enough to answer.

`i` refers to this line that I ran earlier in the code: `for(i in 1:k)` and I set k=8.

`> dim(x)[2]
[1] 1924`

`> max(sig_otu)
[1] 1921`

Comment: If you want to see why/where this is failing, you need to debug the particular method for `predict()` that is being called. In this case it is `predict.randomForest()` but as this is not exported from the package namespace if randomForest you need `debugonce(randomForest:::predict.randomForest`)` to set the debug status on it. Then run the `predict()` line again and step through the code to see where it is failing.

Comment: `rfm <- randomForest(x[-split.idx[[i]]], sig_otu], y[-split.idx[[i]]])` this expression looks like it needs a bit more attention or explanation or both. The square brackets are incorrect (count them). Also, does `i` have a value or is it a loop variable - or is it suppose to represent some formula mode (or should it not be there)?

Comment: The error code says 'vname' is not in the column names or numbers of 'x'. Since we cannot see where 'x' was created, can only suggest you look at `max(sig_otu)` and `dim(x)[2]`

Comment: @RusanKax `i` comes from this line: `for(i in 1:k)`, k=8.

Comment: @BrianLee, I don't see that in the question..so you need to edit the question and add all the details...we cannot guess or mind read, right? Is `k` defined in the question, also? Use the edit button on your question.

Comment: @BondedDust I edited my post to include it

Answer (score 0):

Somthing that worked for me was:

1. Editing the predict.randomForest function. To do so type randomForest:::predict.randomForest (I assume the randomForest package is loaded).
2. Renaming the function. For example, *myrandomForestpredictfun=prediccion.rf=function (object, newdata, type = "response", norm.votes = TRUE, 
         predict.all = FALSE, proximity = FALSE, nodes = FALSE, cutoff, 
         ...)*
3. Commenting the line that contains "x <- x[, vname, drop = FALSE]"
4. Using your new function to get predictions on the training set.